# Access to the path ...\Temp\Assembly-CSharp.dll.mdb" is denied

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm inserting on unity the `Standard Assets` package from the asset store, and I'm getting this error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "C:\Users\Invitado\Desktop\car_ofisial\Temp\Assembly-CSharp.dll.mdb" is denied.

Can anyone tell me please what should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen my answer? Have you tried anything? Is this issue solved?

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off your antivirus or at least the real time scanning feature, I've seen on Google that this could be an antivirus problem.

Sources:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/398470/error-cs0016-in-unity.html
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/628015/access-to-the-path-tempassembly-csharp-firstpassdl.html